# How to copy exact browser configuration to another machine

Tags: firefox, cross-browser

I have 5 pcs with firefox installed. Different installations have different addons and different stuff. On one of them my website works weird. I would like to copy the exact installation to another machine  to see if the problem persist. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maximum compatibility, back up the entire [profile folder](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles) and restore it to the same path on the second machine. Then use `firefox -P "<path to folder>"` to launch Firefox using the copy of the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with firefox it's quite easy and simple. [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/)